# Highcharts - Referance a separate data series in a series tooltip

Tags: highcharts

my desired functionality can be seen at the link below.
However, in my case I'm using an external csv file with the series' in it. When using the external file, the code doesn't have the same functionality. (No tooltip appears on the series 0 & 1)

Is there any change I can make to the code to get it to work with external csv's?

Desired functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/uwbuR/1/

```
        tooltip:{
            formatter:function(){
                var key = this.key;
                if(this.series.index < 1){
                    return 'SERIES 0 '+ this.y + '<br/>SERIES 1 '+this.series.chart.series[1].data[key].y;
                }
                else{
                    return 'Other Series' + this.y;
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: What error message are you receiving in the console?

Comment: Loading external CSV doesn't matter. Maybe you are using categorized xAxis and that's why it doesn't work? In that case try: `var key = this.point.x;`.

Comment: Console Error:
TypeError: this.series.chart.series[1].data[key] is undefined.
Same error when I change var key to this.point.x

Comment: When I use this line of code it works, but obviously I need to link
this.series.chart.series[1].data[1].y;

Comment: Ignore other comment, it timed out.When I use this line of code it works, but it points to the 1st point of data in the other series array, not the this.x value.  
   `this.series.chart.series[1].data[1].y`

Comment: Success!
`var key = this.series.data.indexOf(this.point);
 if(this.series.index < 1)
{return 'SERIES 0 '+ this.y + '<br/>SERIES 1 '
+this.series.chart.series[1].data[key].y;}
else{return 'asd' + this.y;}`